# Encode action names in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

in default asp.net mvc routing the address is something like this:
http://domainname/Controllername/ActionName

my question is:
can I encode the controller name and the action name in the previous URL?

Comment: What is "encode"? What is "previous URL"?

Answer (score -1):

Use Action Name Attribute :

```
    [ActionName("AnotherName")]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View("Login");
    }
```

And, Your Route Will now

```
//localhost:11727/users/AnotherName
```

Instead :

//localhost:11727/users/Login

Comment: thanks for this hint, but what about controller name, can i change in route ?